# Adding custom column to Workflow Task content type makes workflow stop on assign task

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, content-type, column

I have been asking a few questions in here lately, as I'm beggining my journey as a Sharepoint Online 'developer' for my new internship.
I have a new one for today:

I have created a custom approval workflow, and I wanted to collect a comment from the person who will **Approve** or **Reject** the task assigned to him/her by the WF.

I have tried adding a new column called **Approver Comment**, a text column with multiple lines (non-obligatory).

The workflow works, but only until the point where the "Assign task to..." tries to execute. It simply doesn't, but it does if I remove the column I made.
I tried creating a new content type with *Workflow Task(Sharepoint 2013)* as parent, and with it's own comment column, but the same has happened.

The task was never assigned after the inclusion of the column, I would like to know why is it and how can I get it to work.

And please don't recommend using OOTB workflows.

Comment: What environment are you on (e.g. SharePoint Online, SharePoint 2013 on-prem)? Is this a workflow that is being developed in Visual Studio or SharePoint Designer? I'm not going to recommend OOTB workflows because I have created a custom approval workflow and have successfully added several fields with multiple lines of text as the type.

Comment: It's being developed on SharePoint Designer since I'm using SharePoint-online. I have a tag for that.

Comment: That custom "Start approval process" workflow action I told you about has a comments section built in.

Comment: Yeah but in Sharepoint 2013 workflow we don't have that option. Only in 2010

Comment: Which action are you using?

Comment: Like I said, it's all manual. I assign a task and the receiver must approve or reject. The WF waits for the task to be finished. Then it verifies the task result and set the list item to approved or rejected based on the approver's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three things:

1. If the 'Wait for task completion' checkbox is selected on the task
   itself, the workflow will pause execution at that point until the
   task has been completed (approved/rejected).
2. Be sure to select your custom content type in the Outcome Options >
   Task content type dropdown.
3. Be sure to associate your workflow with the Tasks list that contains
   your custom content type.

[image]

You might find the following article helpful:  http://www.jenniferannmason.com/Blog/Post/251/-Office365-and--SharePoint-2013--Creating-Custom-Workflow-Tasks.

Comment: Option 3 fixed it for me. The task list didn't have the custom content type added on it. Thank you ;)